# Eclipse RCP menu

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I am building an eclipse RCP application, and I have one question :

In plugin.xml file, i declared a menu with 5 commands. In summary, it is like this  :

```
Menu A
 subMenu A1
 subMenu A2
```

what I want is to tell to eclipse to evaluate if submenus must be visible only when the the cursor mouse hovers over Main menu item, ie Menu A. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="popup:com.x.sat.ui.views.ProjectsView?after=com.x.sat.ui.commands.closeproject">
         <menu
               icon="icons/repository_rep.gif"
               id="com.x.sat.ui.sgc"
               label="Gestion de Configuration">
            <command
                  commandId="com.x.sat.sgc.ui.addProject"
                  label="Partager le projet"
                  style="push">
               <visibleWhen
                     checkEnabled="false">
                  <reference
                        definitionId="satProjetOrSatModelProjectSelected">
                  </reference>
               </visibleWhen>
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="com.x.sat.sgc.ui.synchronize"
                  label="Synchroniser avec le dépôt ..."
                  style="push">
               <visibleWhen
                     checkEnabled="false">
                  <reference
                        definitionId="synchronizeObject">
                  </reference>
               </visibleWhen>
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="com.x.sat.sgc.ui.browseRepository"
                  label="Parcourir le dépôt...."
                  style="push">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="com.x.sat.sgc.ui.compare"
                  label="Comparer..."
                  style="push">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="com.x.sat.sgc.ui.disconnect"
                  label="Déconnecter le projet ..."
                  style="push">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
```

Comment: which Eclipse version are you using?

Comment: Eclipse Indigo v 3.7.2

Comment: All submenus will automatically open up when mouse pointer hovers on a menu item(If this menu item was the parent of the submenu). Right click on **Navigator or Package view** then hover the mouse pointer on **New** menu item, you will see the submenu  with different menu item like **Project..**, **Example..**, **Other..** etc. This submenu will disappear on moving the mouse pointer to other menu items. To understand your question clearly, add the screen shots(you can upload the screen-shot here http://postimg.org and share link)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you can get this to run using `plugin.xml` and `visiblewhen`.
Since you know the MenuItem that you want to listen to, you can add an [ArmListener](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/events/ArmListener.html) instead.
It will listen to the MenuItem and you can implement the `visibleWhen` commands inside or call some other method that triggers your Items.

```
    ArmListener armListener = new ArmListener() {
    @Override
    public void widgetArmed(ArmEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    };
```

and call it:

```
Menu systemMenu = display.getSystemMenu();
    if (systemMenu != null) {
        MenuItem sysItem = getItem(systemMenu, SWT.ID_QUIT);
        sysItem.addArmListener(armListener);
    }
```

A full example if the usage can be found in this [SWT Snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet354.java)

edit: for a popup menu you can do

```
final Menu tableMenu = new Menu(shell, SWT.POP_UP);
MenuItem item = new MenuItem(tableMenu, SWT.PUSH);
item.setText("Hover Me");
item.addArmListener(armListener);
```

Comment: The menu I want to listen to is a contextual (pop-up) menu in a view, it only appear when user make a right clic, so I can't get it by the way you suggest

Comment: Why not? Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in the past but not sure that the trick matches Eclipse state-of-art; I used a `dynamic` element into my menu declaration and a `sourceProvider` from `org.eclipse.ui.services` extension point.

I guess it should also been applicable to your popup menu.

The class linked to the dynamic element extends `CompoundContributionItem` and override the `getContributionItems()` method in order to update the sourceProvider variable state...  here is the trick not really clean to my mind but it works...

```
@Override
protected IContributionItem[] getContributionItems() {
    SourceProvider.getInstance().updateState();
    return new IContributionItem[0];
}
```

SourceProvider sample:

```
public class SourceProvider extends AbstractSourceProvider {

    private static String ID = "fr.jln.stackoverflow.services.SourceProvider";
    private static String VAR = "fr.jln.stackoverflow.variable1";

    private static final String VAL_TRUE = "TRUE";
    private static final String VAL_FALSE = "FALSE";

    public static SourceProvider getInstance() {
        ISourceProviderService ser = (ISourceProviderService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(ISourceProviderService.class);
        return (SourceProvider) ser.getSourceProvider(ID);
    }

    boolean state = false;

    public SourceProvider() {}

    @Override
    public Map<?, ?> getCurrentState() {
        String value = null;
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(1);

        // fake variable (my id)
        map.put(ID, VAL_TRUE);

        // var state
        value = state ? VAL_TRUE : VAL_FALSE;
        map.put(VAR, value);

        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getProvidedSourceNames() {
        return new String[] { ID, VAR };
    }

    public void updateState() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        state = (min % 2 == 0);
        fireSourceChanged(ISources.WORKBENCH, VAR, state?VAL_TRUE:VAL_FALSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {}
}
```

plugin.xml:

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
         <menu
               label="StackOverflow">
            <command
                  commandId="fr.jln.stackoverflow.command1"
                  label="Command 1"
                  style="push">
               <visibleWhen
                     checkEnabled="false">
                  <with
                        variable="fr.jln.stackoverflow.variable1">
                     <equals
                           value="TRUE">
                     </equals>
                  </with>
               </visibleWhen>
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="fr.jln.stackoverflow.command2"
                  label="Command 2"
                  style="push">
               <visibleWhen
                     checkEnabled="false">
                  <with
                        variable="fr.jln.stackoverflow.variable1">
                     <equals
                           value="FALSE">
                     </equals>
                  </with>
               </visibleWhen>
            </command>
            <dynamic
                  class="ContributionItem"
                  id="fr.jln.stackoverflow.dynamic1">
            </dynamic>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.services">
      <sourceProvider
            provider="SourceProvider">
         <variable
               name="fr.jln.stackoverflow.variable1"
               priorityLevel="workbench">
         </variable>
      </sourceProvider>
   </extension>
```

With this sample, at the result you should have a menu containing 2 items, on which 1 is masked depending on the time...

*Note: some ids can appear quite strange, but sources are extracted from my company plugin*

Hope this could help...